# pgfplots: Plotting one data set with label and the other without label

Tags: pgfplots, labels

I am trying to generate a plot using two data series and have the labels just on one of the series, but not the other. In the following example I would like to see the labels on first \addplot, but not the second.

```
\begin{figure}[htb]    
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[xlabel={$\beta_G$},ylabel={E$_{Peak}$/E$_{acc}$}, 
xmin=0.45, xmax=1.05, 
ymin=1.5, ymax=5.5,
nodes near coords,
every node near coord/.append style={anchor=west},
point meta=explicit symbolic]
\addplot [red, only marks] table[x index=0,y index=1, meta index = 2] {Data.txt};
\addplot [blue] table[x index=0,y index=3] {Data.txt} ;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Two data series.}
\label{fig:two} 
\end{figure}
```

The file Data.txt looks like:

```
#X_value   Y_value     Label   Fit
1            0.6        One     0.5
1.1          0.65       two     0.6
1.2          0.7        three   0.75
```

%-------------------  Edited version

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\tikzstyle{every node}=[font=\footnotesize]
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.3,width=7.5cm, height = 5cm}
\begin{filecontents}{Data.txt}
X_value   Y_value     Label   Fit
1.0          0.6        One     0.5
1.1          0.65       two     0.6
1.2          0.7        three   0.75
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]    
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[xlabel={x},ylabel={y}, 
xmin=0.5, xmax=1.5, 
ymin=0, ymax=1,
nodes near coords,
every node near coord/.append style={anchor=west},
point meta=explicit symbolic]
\addplot [red, only marks] table[x index=0,y index=1, meta index = 2] {Data.txt};
\addplot [blue] table[x index=0,y index=3] {Data.txt} ;
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Two data series.}
\label{fig:two} 
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

and here is the error message I get:

```
! Package pgfplots Error: could not access the 'point meta' (used for example by scatter plots and color maps). Maybe you need to add '\addplot[point meta=y]' or something like that?.
```

If I comment out any of the two \addplot commands, it works.

Comment: Hi mamad, welcome to the site! Could you please edit your question to turn the code snippet into a complete compilable document (starting from `\documentclass`)? That makes it easier for others to start working on a solution. Also, could you describe in a little more detail what's wrong with the result you're currently getting?

Comment: Hi mamad, and welcome to the site. Your x-values (`1`,`1.1`,`1.2`) lie outside your `xmin`-`xmax` range -- that seems a bit odd to me. Same goes for your y-values.

Comment: Hi Jake and John, Thanks for taking the time (Though I have read that I should not thank people in this forum).

Comment: I ran your file and it didn't produce any error message. I think it is performing normally. It adds a plot with only the markers, i.e. no line connecting the points, in red, and write labels on the points, and adds another plot with the same coordinates and connects them with a blue line.
BTW: and yes, instead of saying thanks, you can upvote a comment or an answer. You may also accept an answer if it completely answers your question.

Comment: @mamad: It compiles fine for me, resulting in a blue line plot and three red text labels. What version of PGFPlots are you using?

Comment: @Jake: 
Package: pgfplots 2011/12/29 v1.5.1 (git show 1.5.1-4-g53e640f )

Comment: @mamad: Ah yes, I believe the problem might go away if you update the package (the current version is 1.8)

Comment: Works for me too with the latest release: that makes it 'off-topic' as is fixed by updating.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an issue which is fixed in the latest release.
